# In SwiftUI, how do I get the display width of a string element based on the font

Tags: string, size

I'm trying to get the display width of a string in SwiftUI based on the font characteristics.
something like:

func stringSize(text: String, font: Font) -> (Double, Double)

size = stringSize("This is a test", Font.title)

really just need the width, but getting both OK